# Emulate Menu button Nougat Galaxy S8

Tags: 7.0-nougat, tasker, menu

I miss using the menu key that I used to have on older phones.

I'm able to remap the Bixby key to a Tasker program or any app activity or shortcut, I'm wondering what I would need to do to emulate the menu button if I need something other than Tasker or what I need to do with Tasker to get this to work.

I've tried holding the back button and the recents button which used to work on older Samsung phones

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Holding just the recent button on the s5 opens up the menu. If you're holding back and recent together that might be why it's not working. Have in mind that the menu will only open in apps that designate something as a menu. I'd be surprised if they removed this feature in s8

Comment: @Abochur with the S7 i believe you had to hold back, but neither work on the S8

Comment: And I know that it still accepts the input correctly from a keyboard, I've tested both Bluetooth and wired, both execute the menu key as they should.

Comment: AFAIR there was a way to modify the navigation bar and e.g. add the menu button back. But I don't remember if that was just in *Gravity Box* (Xposed module), or also availabe without root.

Comment: I'd prefer not to be to root my phone

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the xposed module : Xposed Additions ([link](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb)). It allow us to remap any buttons to any effect. Requirement : rooted device + xposed framework installed

Comment: You don't need root to remap keys, I have the Bixby button and the volume buttons are remapped (the single press function is fluctuating until I can use it as menu)